# communicate with website in start up screen in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, shared-objects

Does anybody know a way for a swf file to communicate with the site its placed in. What I mean is I have a flash file with a start up screen in it, which has a tick box saying "Don't show this screen again" which skips to the sites content when tick, the same as what some adobe applications have when first started up. I think this might be able to be done using sharedObjects? But what I can't do is re-activate the start up screen from outside of the flash file. Is sharedObjects the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If you using 9+ swf version you can communicate with javascript and opposite. Then you can save state in cookie or local shared object, just choose better way.